# fancyBox downloading cached images?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've been monitoring the network communications between my browser and my server using Firebug. I see my thumbnails getting downloaded (`200 OK`) as well as the larger versions of the image that are supposed to appear in fancyBox (also `200 OK`). I'm preloading the larger images.

When I click on a thumbnail, the larger image appears in fancyBox. In Firebug, I see that the fancyBox makes a request for the larger image and gets a `304 Not Modified`. This works exactly as I want it, except it seems to only behave like this in Chrome. In FF, it downloads the larger image again -- resulting in `200 OK`.

Any ideas why fancyBox/FF is downloading the image again? And how is it getting a `200 OK` if the resource is already cached?

Comment: You're using the pre-cache option? Might be a bug with their code. Or FF. Either way, it'd be nice to see some code.

Comment: I'm pre-loading the images some other way. That part works. I see it pre-loading in FF, too. My init is just this: `options = {
  openEffect : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none',
  nextEffect : 'none',
  prevEffect : 'none',
  width: "75%",
  height: "75%"
 }`